# Angular2 webpack prebootstrap animation

Tags: angular, webpack

I would like to show an animation ( SplashScreen ) during the app's loading time. I do not want to do it with CSS since I want to be able to use animations and control for how long the splash screen is displayed -> 2 seconds.

Basically I want something like this -> https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3105-creating-a-pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-in-angular-2-rc-1.htm however for the latest (1.0.0-beta.26)  angular2-cli generated project.

Thanks